# Parsing date in Pascal

Tags: date, parsing, pascal

what's the better way of parsing date in Pascal than manually parsing character after character?

Date should be in **mm.dd.yyyy** format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the compiler used.  If you use Delphi have a look at trystrtodate, or (if with a recent Free Pascal) try dateutils.scandatetime

Comment: How about original Turbo Pascal 7.0? :) But still, thanks for answer.

Comment: Throw it away, as you should have in 2000. :) Seriously, maybe you can try to convert the FPC scandatetime code. The strings will be limited to 255 chars, but it does not use particularly new dialect, so backporting it to version of the previous century should be possible.

Comment: Well I'm not doing anything in Pascal, really :) Only C#. I just need to know how to handle such scenario, when I get it at my exam :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Turbo Pascal, then the only thing you can do is check the string character by character. 
Or, you can create a record:

```
          type
           dater = Record
            month: byte;
            day : byte;
            year: integer;
           End;
          var mydate: dater;
```

Thus, knowing the format (**mm.dd.yyyy**) you can easily validate it.
Access the values easily **mydate.month, mydate.day, mydate.year**.